# virtualbox ansible and PHP

Tags: php5, vagrant, ansible

I am trying to install Centos-7 on Ubuntu vivit in Virtual Box using Ansible. I get through a large amount of configuration and set up before it fails with the message below. I have searched for various error types but haven't seen one with mine so I figured I will come here. Can anyone tell me what the errors mean? I suspect it is a failure to install PHP dependencies but I don't why they are failing and how to correct this.

Thanks

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [default]

TASK: [common | check if EPEL is installed] *********************************** 
failed: [default] => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rpmquery epel-release", "delta": "0:00:00.036192", "end": "2015-09-30 19:40:02.697466", "rc": 1, "start": "2015-09-30 19:40:02.661274", "stdout_lines": ["package epel-release is not installed"]}
stdout: package epel-release is not installed
...ignoring

TASK: [common | install EPEL] ************************************************* 
changed: [default]

TASK: [common | clean yum metadata on first run] ****************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [common | upgrade all packages on first run] **************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | MariaDB Install] ********************************************* 
changed: [default] => (item=mariadb-server)

TASK: [mariadb | MariaDB my.cnf] ********************************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | Starting MariaDB] ******************************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | Enabled MariaDB Service] ************************************* 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | Ensure DB user exists] *************************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | Ensure DB exists] ******************************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [mariadb | Import ConnectDB] ******************************************** 
changed: [default]

TASK: [php | Install PHP Packages] ******************************************** 
failed: [default] => (item=php,php-devel,php-pecl-zendopcache,php-mbstring,php-xml,php-mysql,php-gd,php-pdo,php-drush-drush,php-json,libmcrypt-devel,libmcrypt,php-mcrypt) => {"failed": true, "item": "php,php-devel,php-pecl-zendopcache,php-mbstring,php-xml,php-mysql,php-gd,php-pdo,php-drush-drush,php-json,libmcrypt-devel,libmcrypt,php-mcrypt"}
msg: unsupported parameter for module: update_cache

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/jcorbett/playbook.retry

default                    : ok=12   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=1   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `msg: unsupported parameter for module: update_cache`

Comment: It would really help if you could specify at least the task and module that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without see the playbook, I can only assume here. It seems like you are using a unsupported parameter as suggested [here](https://github.com/phred/5minbootstrap/issues/1).

```
- name: Run yum upgrade
action: command yum upgrade
```